# Adding interactions in formula interface in R randomForest

Tags: r, random-forest

`rf = randomForest(Species ~.^4, data = iris)
varImpPlot(rf)`

instead of added interactions `varImpPlot` shows only four variables, is it realy use additional interactions ?

Answer (score 1):

Yup. The interactions terms are included in your rf:

```
attr(rf$terms, "term.labels")

 [1] "Sepal.Length"                                      "Sepal.Width"                                      
 [3] "Petal.Length"                                      "Petal.Width"                                      
 [5] "Sepal.Length:Sepal.Width"                          "Sepal.Length:Petal.Length"                        
 [7] "Sepal.Length:Petal.Width"                          "Sepal.Width:Petal.Length"                         
 [9] "Sepal.Width:Petal.Width"                           "Petal.Length:Petal.Width"                         
[11] "Sepal.Length:Sepal.Width:Petal.Length"             "Sepal.Length:Sepal.Width:Petal.Width"             
[13] "Sepal.Length:Petal.Length:Petal.Width"             "Sepal.Width:Petal.Length:Petal.Width"             
[15] "Sepal.Length:Sepal.Width:Petal.Length:Petal.Width"
```

Comment: so why I don't see them in `varImpPlot(rf)` plot ?